# Extract an .mzp on Ubuntu

Tags: compression

As above, is there any way to perform an extraction of a .mzp file on Ubuntu?

The interwebs have nothing for me :p.

Comment: The intwerwebz do have something, have you tried with **WinArchiver**?. *Mzp file stands for mountable zip file. It is the native format for [WinArchiver](http://www.winarchiver.com/index.htm)*

Comment: Yeah I saw that but I don't see any release geared towards Linux... unless I am blind :p

Comment: It doesn't work with File Roller?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MZP is a "mountable zip file" and [it's proprietary to WinArchiver](http://www.winarchiver.com/tutorials/mzp-file.htm). That doesn't help you because WinArchiver is, as the name suggests, built for Windows. That also means that other archiving tools don't know the format so won't be of any use.

Your immediate options:

- Download WinArchiver and run it in Wine. This may not work.
- Create a Virtual Machine for a Windows installation, install WinArchiver and unWinArchive the file.
- Slap the person who sent you it and tell them to use a standard archiving format.

There are other options, including breaking into national embassies and holding diplomats hostage, but I really hope you're not that desperate to get into this file.

Short answer: use the tool it was created with.

Comment: Extraction with WinArchiver works in Wine on Ubuntu Lucid.

Comment: I logged in to AskUbuntu just to upvote this answer. :')